# How does Visual Studio run a web service locally?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0

I am developing a web service from a WCF service application, and I run Visual Studio 2010 Pro and reference the `localhost:<port>/<service>` created by Visual Studio from my Windows Forms project at the same solution.

How can Visual Studio run the web service locally without installing the web service? Can I deploy my web service using the same method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio has a built in ASP.NET development server.

You can't deploy your service like that - in order for your clients to use your web service you must first set up a web server (like IIS, for instance).

Although it is possible to expose your web service to other parties using the ASP.NET development server, it's not a good approach to keep it that way. It is meant solely for development.

Comment: Do you know the exact Service Name of the ASP.Net Development Server? I can't find it in the services.msc, the ASP.Net Development Server is currently running on my PC.

Comment: It's not running as a service; it's being executed once you press the 'Play' or 'Debug' button in VS.

Comment: Once it's running, the process is called 'WebDev.Webserver40.exe' (I'm running .NET 4.0, so other framework version won't have the '40' part appended)